# Some help to make AS3 and ZendAMF work together

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3, zend-amf

after some research I found that the best option for my current proyect is to use AS3 in collaboration with ZendAMF to be able to connect with PHP->MySql.

But, there is a little problem, I cant make it work, and maybe its me, but the official (official website) documentation kind of sucks.

So, is there a proper guide to have a working example using ZendAMF?

Thx very much.

Edit.: Im not using Flex components, thou Im using Flash Builder my project is entirely AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial: http://corlan.org/2008/11/13/flex-and-php-remoting-with-zend-amf/